# Unable to connect to OpenVPN client in Docker

Tags: docker, openvpn

I have tried to set up an OpenVPN client under docker, using the [dperson/openvpn-client](https://github.com/dperson/openvpn-client) image. I get the following error:

`UDPv6: Address not available (code=99)`

When googling this problem, I've come across [this discussion](https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?t=24975), but I'm not sure how to look at the client and server logs separately.

I'have the full logs on [pastebin here](https://pastebin.com/haK5PC8d)

I am able to get the IP of my home address inside the container, but not the IP from the VPN. I appreciate any help
!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the TLS handshake fails.
I extracted this from your logs:

```
TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
```

Make sure your server is setup correctly.